# Cross compiling OpenSSL

Tags: linux, configuration, openssl, arm, cross-compiling

I am on ubuntu x86-64 and trying to compile OpenSSL for ARM/AARCH64/i686 using compile options -g -gdwarf-4 -O3 with clang and gcc, and using the following commands to do so, but can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm following instructions laid out by both OpenSSL as well as BinKit but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

For aarch64 for example:

```
./Configure linux-generic64 shared --cross-compiler-prefix="\aarch64-ubuntu-linux-gnu-\" -g -O2 -gdwarf-4
```

which results in:
"unrecognized command line: aarch64-ubuntu-linux-gnu"

and when I try to pass the parameters to ./config instead, I get the error:
"unrecognized command line option: -m64"

I know the issue is me not typing the proper command, but I also can't figure how to do it!

Comment: @Frant I made sure that aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc is installed on my system and it is! same goes for i686 and ARM. I tried adding the path to the bin directory of aarch64, and got the following:
```
--cross-compiler-prefix=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-'
```
I made sure that I have aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc installed, but this is the only directory where I could find any relevant executables (or at least I think they're relevant)

Comment: I augmented the answer with a complete, working procedure you should be able to use as is for building for linux-aarch64.

Comment: Did the answer help you solving your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the entire prefix.
For example, if you want to use:
`/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc`
as the compiler, use:
`--cross-compile-prefix=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-`
when specifying the `--cross-compile-prefix` option.

An example of a complete, working procedure targeting linux aarch64 would therefore be:

```bash
# Retrieve openssl.
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.1.1.tar.gz

# Retrieve a toolchain I know is working.
wget "https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/12.2.rel1/binrel/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz?rev=6750d007ffbf4134b30ea58ea5bf5223&hash=6C7D2A7C9BD409C42077F203DF120385AEEBB3F5" -O arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz

# Install the toolchain.
mkdir -p /opt/arm/12
tar Jxf arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz  -C /opt/arm/12

# Build openssl for linux aarch64.
tar zxf openssl-3.1.1.tar.gz
cd openssl-3.1.1
./Configure linux-aarch64 --cross-compile-prefix=/opt/arm/12/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu- --prefix=/opt/openssl-3.1.1 --openssldir=/opt/openssl-3.1.1 -static -g -O2 -gdwarf-4
make install

# Verify executables were built.
ls -gG /opt/openssl-3.1.1/bin/
total 28372
-rwxr-xr-x 1     6884 Jun 15 22:14 c_rehash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 29065376 Jun 15 22:14 openss

# Display information on executable.
file /opt/openssl-3.1.1/bin/openssl
/opt/openssl-3.1.1/bin/openssl: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, with debug_info, not stripped

# Display openssl version using qemu-system-aarch64.
/opt/qemu-8.0.2/bin/qemu-aarch64 /opt/openssl-3.1.1/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023)
```

Configuring for `linux-generic64` using the same procedure seems to be working as well:

```bash
./Configure linux-generic64 --cross-compile-prefix=/opt/arm/12/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu- --prefix=/opt/openssl-3.1.1 --openssldir=/opt/openssl-3.1.1 -static -g -O2 -gdwarf-4
make all

file apps/openssl
./apps/openssl: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```